WatchOS and watch pair app to show the iPhone app Camera view in companion app
In watchOS I desire to see/mirror the paired iPhone screen or even a view programatically.
So when the iPhone App starts up the watch companion app opens and shows either the entire iPhone screen, or when iPhone app gets to the Camera View to have that CameraView Mirror automatically show on the iWatch. I have seen other app do this, but I can not see how to accomplish this with code. thanks.
